# PHP Laravel form to take day/hour input and set expire time

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

I want to make a form of user posts. The form will contain post title, post description and post expire time. There will be a database column where I will store the post expire time. Table columns will be:

```
id | user_id | post_title | post_description | post_status | post_expire_time
```

Suppose user has given 4 hours in the expire time. The `post_status` will be `not-expired` by default and. After 4 hour, the `post_status` will be converted to `expired`. How to do that in a Laravel app?

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine 2 ways to do this:

#### Way 1: Save how long the post lives and remember the time of post creation

- In your database field `post_expire_hours` you save the hours (or minutes, depends on what the shortest time period you want to allow) the post is considered as `not-expired`
  (e.g. `4` as integer).
- In a second field `post_created` you save when the post was created
  (e.g. `2016-04-28 12:00` as timestamp).

The post status is not required as a database field because it can be calculated from:

```
if (now > post_created + post_expire_hours) {
    // expired
} else {
    // not-expired
}
```

In this way you are able to determine how long the post was alive by looking into `post_expire_hours`.

#### Way 2: Save the exact point in time when the post expires

- In your database field `post_expire_time` you save the exact time when the post expires
  (e.g. `2016-04-28 16:00` as timestamp).

The post status is not required as a database field because it is calculated from:

```
if (now > post_expire_time) {
    // expired
} else {
    // not-expired
}
```

In this way you are not able to determine how long the post was alive.

Answer (score 0):

You need something that updates the rows automatically. Fortunately, Laravel has [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling) for that.

To use it, you must create one (1) cronjob which runs each minute. You then configure your schedule in code. Something like this:

```
// In the App\Console\Kernel class:

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        // Update your post_status here 
    })->hourly();
}
```